# Create Play Framework 2.4.x filter

Tags: scala, playframework

I've made a test filter that should print headers to console

```
package filters
import play.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

class SessionVerifier extends Filter {
    def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
      nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
        Logger.debug(requestHeader.headers.toString())
        result
      }
    }
}
```

and add it to my filter list:

```
class Filters @Inject() (csrfFilter: CSRFFilter, sessionVerifier: SessionVerifier) extends HttpFilters {
  def filters = Seq(csrfFilter, sessionVerifier)
}
```

But it doesn't print anything to console. CSRFFilter works fine.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your logback.xml to see where the logging output goes?

Comment: It was that :) You can add you comment as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `conf/logback.xml` - it's probable that your logging config isn't dumping anything to the console.